# How do i write Captcha solver for my autoregistration code?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, captcha, auto-registration

I want to make an autoregistretion code for aminoapps
i'l provide you code i already did,
i write it on requests and many more libs

I already wrote authorisation on tempmail site, getting email, getting link from inbox and then download it, next i want to !Maybe delete the background and make it white so text-to-image site would recognize symbols!
any ideas please? maybe examples or working codes of working captcha's solvers?
here's the code:

```
def check_inbox():
        request = requests.get(f'https://temporarymail.com/ajax/?action=checkInbox&value={linkGenerate_password}').json()
        view_id = next(iter(request))
        print(view_id)


        request_block_mail = requests.get(f'https://temporarymail.com/view/?i={view_id}').text

        sup_for_block = BeautifulSoup(request_block_mail, 'lxml')
        divs = sup_for_block.find('div')
        url = divs.find('a').get('href').replace('hxxp:','http:')
        image_bytes = requests.get(url).content
        with open(f'captcha.jpg','wb') as file:
            file.write(image_bytes)

        print(f'url-adress: {url}')
        print(f'saved_captcha')

    def captcha_solve():
        input_path = 'captcha.jpg'
        output_path = 'output.jpg'
        open_image = Image.open(input_path)
        output_image = remove(open_image)
        output_image.save(output_path)
        #that doesn't work here 'OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```